# mysql with duplicate key

Tags: mysql

I tried searching online for this...I had a row that I inserted into the database. I removed it. The table has a Unique Key on a particular column. When I try to insert a new row with the same value for the unique key, it fails saying duplicate entry. However, there is no duplicate entry since the row is not there! Is there a way to reset this?

I would like the table to accept values that are unique to what is there right now. I tried to remove the unique key constraint from the table to see if that would work, however, when I added it back, it was having the same issue.

Comment: That is not normal behavior. Can you elaborate on the data structure, what columns are in the key, et cetera? A `UNIQUE` key should only evaluate data that actually exist, not data that may have one time existed in the past.

Comment: I'm interested in what tools are used here; is it just a shell - or some kind of ...myAdmin stuff.

Comment: Are you passing in the unique value in your SQL statement or relying on the DB to do so (and you're only passing in the other values)?

Comment: The row was created in the `auth_user` table (in Django) by my web app. I removed the row manually and tried to enter the user again myself. That is where I got this issue.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple The data consists of email addresses for the user, I put a unique constraint on that information

Comment: try to make an `analyze table` to fix the index on the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you perform dirty reading? and the deletion did not commit? try use the read commit option, I think it's called isolation level.